# ExtJs 3.4 : Get all records from a grid and pass them into a servlet

Tags: servlets, extjs, grid, store

I have a grid store and I want to get all the records from that grid and push them into an array. And also I want to pass this array of data to a servlet to save them in a database. Here is my attempt.

```
var tourData = plannedGridStore.getRange();
var gridData = new Array();
tourData.each(function (record) {
    gridData.push(record.data);
});
```

But my firebug console says

```
.each(function (record) { is not a function
```

I am using ExtJs 3.4. What's wrong with my code ?

And also I need to know how should I pass my gridData array to a servlet.

Please help me

Cheers

Comment: You are missing the closing `}` form the last line fo the function, is this a typo here?

Comment: No no.It's a mistake when I posting this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Ext.data.Store` [`getRange`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-getRange) method returns array of records. For iterates this array you can use [`Ext.each()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext-method-each) method:

```
Ext.each(tourData, function (record) {
    gridData.push(record.data);
});
```

For sending your array data to server you can use [`Ext.Ajax.request`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.Ajax-method-request) method. You can not pass array as request parameter so firstly you have to encoced it to JSON with [`Ext.util.JSON.encode()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.util.JSON-method-encode) method.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'YOUR_URL',
    params: { 
       gridData: Ext.util.JSON.encode(gridData)
    }
});
```

Comment: This works fine.Thanx a lot. Can you please tell me hoe should I recieve this gridData array in my servlet?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a POST you can do something pretty succinct like:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'url',
    jsonData: Ext.pluck(store.getRange(), 'data')
});
```

Comment: Glad to learn about `Ext.pluck`, which works very well in this context, thanks!